# While passing address in nodejs, when to place '/' between directories and when to place '\\' . And why do we place dot(.) before writing addresses

Tags: node.js, nodejs-server, npm-live-server

While passing address in nodejs, when to place '/' between directories and when to place '\' .  And why do we place dot(.) before writing addresses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path) package provides functionality so that you don't need to worry about what directory separator you need to use.

```
const path = require('path');
path.join(parentDir, childDir);
```

And dot represents current directory i.e.

```
project index file path: /home/user/projects/project-name/index.js
you are in <project-name> folder
so index file path will be ./index.js
```

Answer (score 0):

In a Unix/Linux environments you place a forward slash as a folder seperator.

e.g. /home/user/image.jpg

In a Windows system you use backslashes as folder seperators, since a backslash is also an escape character in a string you should escape the backslash.

e.g. C:\users\user\image.jpg

You use a . for relative paths.
e.g. if your script runs in /home/user/ and you want to access image.jpg you can do so by ./image.jpg

for more info: https://nodejs.org/api/path.html